# Is there a function in Julia for dumping the field values of a type into a tuple?

Tags: types, julia

Something like this works

```
struct MyStruct
    x
    y
    z
end

x = MyStruct(1, 2, 3)

a, b, c = ntuple(i -> getfield(x, fieldnames(MyStruct)[i]), length(fieldnames(MyStruct)))
```

but I can't help but think I'm just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't know of a single function or macro to do this but `map(i->getfield(x, i), fieldnames(typeof(x)))` is at least a little more compact.

Comment: or `getfield.(Ref(x), fieldnames(typeof(x)))`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Oh, so `getfield` *is* vectorized. I thought it wasn't. Why is `Ref()` necessary here?

Comment: `Ref` is needed because you want `x` to be protected against being broadcasted over (it might be a collection that defines `axes`). You can also write `(x,)` or `[x]` to perform the "protection" task.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Got it, thanks. Since your suggestion allows `getfield` to be vectorized in a straightforward way, I consider it "the answer" if you want to submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `getfield` over names of fields like this:

```
getfield.(Ref(x), fieldnames(typeof(x)))
```

You can also replace `Ref(x)` with `(x,)` or `[x]` to protect `x` against being broadcasted over. Here is an example how you could silently get a wrong result:

```
julia> using NamedArrays

julia> x = NamedArray(fill((array=1, dicts=2, dimnames=3),3))
3-element Named Array{NamedTuple{(:array, :dicts, :dimnames),Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}},1}
A  │
───┼─────────────────────────────────────
1  │ (array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3)
2  │ (array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3)
3  │ (array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3)

julia> getfield.(Ref(x), fieldnames(typeof(x))) # correct
(NamedTuple{(:array, :dicts, :dimnames),Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}}[(array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3), (array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3), (array = 1, dicts = 2, dimnames = 3)], (OrderedCollections.OrderedDict("1"=>1,"2"=>2,"3"=>3),), (:A,))

julia> getfield.(x, fieldnames(typeof(x))) # wrong
3-element Named Array{Int64,1}
A  │
───┼──
1  │ 1
2  │ 2
3  │ 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, there are two alternatives: `ntuple` and generated functions. A baseline is to manually write the code (which could be generated by a macro).

`ntuple` usually generates better code, and in this case is more than 20 times faster.

```
struct Foo{A, B}
    a::A
    b::B
end

dump0(x) = getfield.(Ref(x), fieldnames(typeof(x)))
dump1(x) = ntuple(i -> getfield(x, i), fieldcount(typeof(x)))

# Based off https://discourse.julialang.org/t/slowness-of-fieldnames-and-propertynames/55364/2
@generated function  dump2(obj::T) where {T}
    return :((tuple($((
        :(getfield(obj, $i)) for i in 1:fieldcount(obj)
    )...))))
end

# hardcoded
dump3(x::Foo) = (x.a, x.b)
```

`@code_llvm dump3(Foo(1,2))` and `@code_llvm dump2(Foo(1,2))` are the same, whereas `@code_llvm dump1(Foo(1,2))` and `@code_llvm dump0(Foo(1,2))` are much complicated.

To get timings, define

```
eq0(a, b) = ==(dump0(a), dump0(b))
eq1(a, b) = ==(dump1(a), dump1(b))
eq2(a, b) = ==(dump2(a), dump2(b))
eq3(a, b) = ==(dump3(a), dump3(b))
```

(These equality functions will behave differently than the default defined on `Foo` with respect to `missing` and `NaN`. Another motivation for dumping to a tuple is to define e.g. `hash(x::Foo, s::UInt) = hash(dump(x), hash(Foo, s))`

I was not able to find a performance benchmark that shows a considerable difference between `dump1` and the `dump2`, even though the code generated for `dump2` is seemingly more efficient. `dump0` is much slower:

```
julia> b = @benchmarkable eq0(Foo(a, b), Foo(c, d)) setup=((a, b, c, d) = rand(0:5, 4))
Benchmark(evals=1, seconds=5.0, samples=10000)

julia> run(b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  1.217 μs … 46.291 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     1.269 μs              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.417 μs ±  1.145 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%
[...]

 Memory estimate: 448 bytes, allocs estimate: 14.

julia> b = @benchmarkable eq1(Foo(a, b), Foo(c, d)) setup=((a, b, c, d) = rand(0:5, 4))
Benchmark(evals=1, seconds=5.0, samples=10000)

julia> run(b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  37.000 ns …  18.596 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     41.000 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   43.594 ns ± 185.778 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%
[...]

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> b = @benchmarkable eq2(Foo(a, b), Foo(c, d)) setup=((a, b, c, d) = rand(0:5, 4))
Benchmark(evals=1, seconds=5.0, samples=10000)

julia> run(b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  40.000 ns …  13.651 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     44.000 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   46.200 ns ± 152.346 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%
[...]

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> b = @benchmarkable eq3(Foo(a, b), Foo(c, d)) setup=((a, b, c, d) = rand(0:5, 4))
Benchmark(evals=1, seconds=5.0, samples=10000)

julia> run(b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  40.000 ns … 168.000 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     44.000 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   43.878 ns ±   2.114 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%
[...]

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```